# Finding non-bouncy numbers under 10^x

Tags: java, performance

I am trying to find non bouncy numbers under \$10^x\$ where \$1\le x\le 1000\$.
\$123456\$ is an *increasing number* where every digit is greater than or equal to the previous digit (\$1223344\$ is also counted as an increasing number).
Similarly a *decreasing number* is one where every digit is smaller than or equal to the previous digit (\$443322\$ is also counted as an decreasing number).

155224 such numbers, which are neither increasing, nor decreasing, are bouncy numbers, such that 12951 numbers below one-million that are not bouncy. I want to find number of non bouncy number under \$10^x\$.

My code works perfectly fine, but when \$n\$ is greater than 7, it takes way too much time to give the output! So, it needs performance optimizations.

```
import java.util.*;
class A{
static String s;
public static void main(String z[]){
    int n,i;
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    n=sc.nextInt();
    int input[]=new int[n];
    int output[]=new int[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        input[i]=sc.nextInt();
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        output[i]=noOfBouncy(input[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        System.out.println(output[i]);
    }
}
public static boolean isIncreasing(String s){
     int len=s.length();
     for(int i=0;i<len-1;i++){
         if(s.charAt(i)>s.charAt(i+1)){
             return false;
         }
    }
return true;    
}
public static boolean isDecreasing(String s){
     int len=s.length();
     for(int i=0;i<len-1;i++){
         if(s.charAt(i)<s.charAt(i+1)){
             return false;
         }
    }
return true;
}
public static int noOfBouncy(int k){
int limit=(int)Math.pow(10,k);
int count=0;
int num=1;
while(num<limit){
    s=new String(Integer.toString(num));
    if(isIncreasing(s) || isDecreasing(s) ){
    }
    else{
       count++;
    }
    num++;
  }
count=limit-count;
return count-1; 
}
}
```

Comment: (This is a brute force approach. However the math is tantalizing for noOfBouncy. Decreasing is the reversal of Increasing (the same amounts), and their union consists of 1111....111, 22...22 and such. For two digits: All - Incr - Decr - Eq = 100 - 45 - 45 - 10 = 0 and so on)

Comment: You know that 10^1000 is a Very Big Number, right? double caps out around 10^300.

Comment: Specifically, `(int)Math.pow(10,k);` hits Integer.MAX_VALUE at k=10. So your code only works for K from 1 to 9. Beyond that you need to use `BigInteger`, which is going to make things slower, not faster.

Comment: Finally, please note this user is working on Project Euler 113

Comment: How do you categorise single digit numbers? Are those bouncy or not?

Comment: @Smac89 yes they are considered bouncy.

Comment: Going by your definition, I would say that single-digit numbers are *both* increasing and decreasing, and therefore certainly not bouncy.

Comment: @Rhialto: I'd say likewise for numbers consisting of repetitions of the same digit: 22, 555, 9999999, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not a review but an expanded comment.

Brute force is bad. Do some math first.

Consider a non-decreasing number of length \$n\$ formed by  exactly \$k\$ given digits. It has exactly \$k - 1\$ transitions from a digit to a larger one, and there are exactly \$n - 1\$ places where the transition may happen, so there are \$\binom{n-1}{k-1}\$ such numbers. The \$\binom{10}{k}\$ ways to pick \$k\$ digits give a subtotal of \$\binom{n-1}{k-1}\binom{10}{k}\$, and a grand total is \$\sum_{k=1}^{10}\binom{n-1}{k-1}\binom{10}{k}\$.

So the problem nails down to efficient calculation of binomial coefficients, which in this case is fairly straightforward, since you never need more than 10 factors.

Comment: Doing just a little more math, the given sum is equal to \$ {n+9\choose n} \$, also obtainable by the stars-and-bars method.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro You are absolutely correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

### Correctness

Your code reports a different number of bouncy numbers than both @GentianKasa and myself, so either there was a transcription error on one of our parts or you have a bug.

Your code does not work for k > 9 because you're restricting yourself to int, while 10^1000 is much, much bigger than that.

Finally, I'm going to leave this up because it does review your code, but @vnp's approach is *clearly* the correct one.

### Performance

On my machine, this consistently runs marginally faster than @GentianKasa's code (3/4 of a second for k=8), assuming the same `BigInteger`-based framework for numbers. The number of computations we're talking about for k > 7 is immense, so I don't see any algorithm being able to do this much faster. There are probably some micro-optimizations that would help it a little.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public final class CharBouncyNumbers {

    public static BigInteger countNonBouncyNumbers(final int k) {
        if (k > 1000) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("K must be less than or equal to 1000");
        }

        long count = 0;
        BigInteger bigCount = BigInteger.ZERO;

        final BigInteger bigMaxNumber = BigInteger.TEN.pow(k);
        final long maxNumber = bigMaxNumber.longValue();
        for (long i = 0; i < maxNumber; i++) {
            if (!isBouncy(Long.toString(i).toCharArray())) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        if (maxNumber < Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            return BigInteger.valueOf(count);
        }

        for (BigInteger i = BigInteger.valueOf(maxNumber); i.compareTo(bigMaxNumber) < 0; i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
            if (!isBouncy(i.toString().toCharArray())) {
                if (count != Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                    count++;
                } else {
                    bigCount = bigCount.add(BigInteger.ONE);
                }
            }
        }
        return bigCount.add(BigInteger.valueOf(count));
    }

    public static boolean isBouncy(final char[] number) {
        if (number.length < 3) {
            return false;
        }

        boolean increasing = false;
        boolean decreasing = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < number.length - 1; i++) {
            increasing |= (number[i] > number[i + 1]);
            decreasing |= (number[i] < number[i + 1]);
            if (increasing && decreasing) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(final String argv[]) {
        final int k = 8;
        final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Found " + countNonBouncyNumbers(k));
        final long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final long durationMillis = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println("Executed k=" + k + " in " + durationMillis + " milliseconds");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it should be possible to decrease you complexity from linear (in \$10^x\$  for your brute force version) to linear in \$ x \$.

I'm sketching the algorithm only, I'm not writing it out in detail. Also, I'm limiting myself to increasing numbers (since the number of decreasing ones is the same, as remarked by @Joop Eggen).

The idea is to use induction on \$x\$: find the count of increasing numbers of length \$ x+1 \$ given the count of the numbers of length \$ x \$.

To do that, we should keep counts for each initial digit, so if we go up to length `N` we need `count[N][10]`;

Of course `count[0][i] = 1` for each i in 0...9: all 1-digit numbers are increasing.

Then we go prepend a digit p: count[1][p]. How many increasing numbers starting with digit p are there? This can be found from the shorter numbers. If the next digit is equal or higher, those contribute. If not, then not.
So `count[1][p]` is the sum of `count[0][p...9]`.
A special case is `count[1][0]` since prepending a 0 doesn't change the value so we probably don't want to count those. So that would leave `count[n][0]` all 1 (or undefined).

Clearly I left the induction variable implicit here.

When you reach the desired length for the numbers, the total number of increasing numbers is simply the total of all these partial sums.

The number of non-bouncy numbers is the number of increasing numbers + the number of decreasing numbers (which is the same) minus the overlap (which is 9 for each length: `1111`, `2222`, ..., `9999`).

And finally the number of bouncy numbers, for completeness, is \$ 10^x \$ minus the number of non-bouncy numbers.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Good job on your first answer.

Answer (score 1):

Except for indentation (which I'm guessing is like this only on the question) the code seems pretty readable.

Regarding performance I'd have some suggestions:

- Don't check numbers `<= 100` as they are never bouncy (this means that for \$x <= 2\$ you'll always have \$10^x\$ as a result),
- Work with `char[]` instead of `string`,
- Check `char`s only once (you're doing it twice).

The resulting code should be something like the following (not tested):

```
public int countNonBouncyNumbers(int limit){
    if(limit <= 100){
        return limit;
    }

    return limit - countBouncyNumbers(limit);
}

public int countBouncyNumbers(int limit){
    int counter = 0;

    for(int i = 101; i <= limit; i++){
        if(isBouncy(i)){
            counter++;
        }
    }

    return counter;
}

public boolean isBouncy(int number){
    char[] digits = Integer.toString(number).toCharArray();
    boolean isIncreasing = false;
    boolean isDecreasing = false;

    for(int i = 1; i < digits.length; i++){
        if(digits[i] < digits[i - 1]){
            if(isIncreasing){
                return true;
            }
            isDecreasing = true;
        } else if(digits[i] > digits[i - 1]){
            if(isDecreasing){
                return true;
            }
            isIncreasing = true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Another way to go at it (which I personally like the most) would be by using the `/` and `%` operators and not managing `char`s and `string`s. In this case, the `isBouncy` would become something like the following (still not tested):

```
public boolean isBouncy(int number){
    int previousMod, currentMod = number % 10;
    boolean isIncreasing = false, isDecreasing = false;

    do{
        previousMod = currentMod;
        number = number / 10;
        currentMod = number % 10;

        if(previousMod > currentMod){
            if(isDecreasing){
                return true;
            }

            isIncreasing = true;
        } else if(previousMod < currentMod){
            if(isIncreasing){
                return true;
            }

            isDecreasing = true;
        }
    } while(number > 0);

    return false;
}
```

Also, regarding the magnitude of the numbers, I'm assuming you're going to use `BigInteger`s once you get the algorithm up-and-running, otherwise you won't be able to manage the range of numbers you indicated.

Comment: I believe OP is trying to find `non bouncy numbers`, i.e. your `if-statement` should read `if(!isBouncy(i)) { .. }`

Comment: @Smac89 you're right. I misread the question. Thanks

Comment: The code above does not compile. Java does not have `int.toString()` or `bool`. Instead, do `Integer.toString(int)` and `boolean`.

Comment: @TheCoffeeCup thanks. I haven't been programming in Java since version 4 and don't remember stuff that well. Thanks for the heads-up.